# Python regex output random duplication

Tags: python, regex, duplicates

I have a log file having the following format. I have only included a small part to highlight the issue that I am having when I use Python's regex to extract some relevant information.

```
Time = 1

smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.230812, Final residual = 0.0134171, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.283614, Final residual = 0.0158797, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.190444, Final residual = 0.016567, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0850116, Final residual = 0.00375608, No Iterations 3
time step continuity errors : sum local = 0.00999678, global = 0.00142109, cumulative = 0.00142109
smoothSolver:  Solving for omega, Initial residual = 0.00267604, Final residual = 0.000166675, No Iterations 3
bounding omega, min: -26.6597 max: 18468.7 average: 219.43  
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 1, Final residual = 0.0862096, No Iterations 2
ExecutionTime = 4.84 s  ClockTime = 5 s


Time = 2

smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.0299872, Final residual = 0.00230507, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.145767, Final residual = 0.00882969, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.0863129, Final residual = 0.00858536, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.394189, Final residual = 0.0175138, No Iterations 3
time step continuity errors : sum local = 0.00862823, global = 0.00212477, cumulative = 0.00354587
smoothSolver:  Solving for omega, Initial residual = 0.00258475, Final residual = 0.000222705, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 0.112805, Final residual = 0.0054572, No Iterations 3
ExecutionTime = 5.9 s  ClockTime = 6 s

Time = 3

smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.128298, Final residual = 0.0070293, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.138825, Final residual = 0.0116437, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.0798979, Final residual = 0.00491246, No Iterations 3
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.108748, Final residual = 0.00429273, No Iterations 2
time step continuity errors : sum local = 0.0073211, global = -0.00187909, cumulative = 0.00166678
smoothSolver:  Solving for omega, Initial residual = 0.00238456, Final residual = 0.000224435, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 0.0529661, Final residual = 0.00280851, No Iterations 3
ExecutionTime = 6.92 s  ClockTime = 7 s
```

My code is as follows:

```
# Opening the log file for reading
with open(logFile, 'r') as logfile_read:
    for line in logfile_read:
        line = line.rstrip()

        # To extract Time or iteration
        if 'Time' in line:
            iteration_time = re.findall(r'^Time\s+=\s+(.*)', line)

        # To extract local, global and cumulative values
        if 'local' in line:
            local_global_cumu = re.findall(r'sum\s+local\s+=\s+(.*),\s+global\s+=\s+(.*),\s+cumulative\s+=\s+(.*)', line)
             if local_global_cumu:
                local_global_cumu = local_global_cumu[0]
                (cont_Local, cont_Global, cont_Cumulative) = local_global_cumu
            for t in iteration_time:
                contLocal.write("%s\t%s\n" %(t, cont_Local))
                contGlobal.write("%s\t%s\n" %(t, cont_Global))
                contCumulative.write("%s\t%s\n" %(t, cont_Cumulative))

        # To extract kinetic energy residual values
        if 'k,' in line:
            kinetic_energy = re.findall(r'k,\s+Initial\s+residual\s+=\s+(.*),\s+Final\s+residual\s+=\s+(.*),\s+No\s+Iterations\s+(.*)', line)
            if kinetic_energy:
                kinetic_energy = kinetic_energy[0]
                (k_initial, k_FinalRes, k_Iters) = kinetic_energy
            for t in iteration_time:
                k.write("%s\t%s\n" %(t, k_initial))
                kFinalRes.write("%s\t%s\n" %(t, k_FinalRes))
                kIters.write("%s\t%s\n" %(t, k_Iters))

        # To extract omega residual values
        if 'omega,' in line:
            omega_values = re.findall(r'omega,\s+Initial\s+residual\s+=\s+(.*),\s+Final\s+residual\s+=\s+(.*),\s+No\s+Iterations\s+(.*)', line)
            if omega_values:
                omega_rate = omega_values[0]
                (omega_initial, omega_FinalRes, omega_Iters) = omega_rate
            for t in iteration_time:
                print ("%s\t%s\n" %(t, omega_initial))
```

The last part (To extract omega residual values), `omega_initial` is printing randomly duplicate values. The output of `print ("%s\t%s\n" %(t, omega_initial))` is shown below:

```
1   0.00267604

1   0.00267604

2   0.00258475

3   0.00238456
```

I am unable to understand why the first set of values is written twice, while there is only one such value in the log file that is being read. This type of duplication is occurring randomly for many values when the full log file is processed.

This behaviour is not observed for any of the previous variables present in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reason out why I was getting duplicate values. In my log file I have two instances of `omega` and thus it was extracting twice as far as my understanding goes. The trick was this. Instead of `if 'omega,' in line:`, I have now `if 'Solving for omega,' in line:` and this solves the problem.

```
if 'Solving for omega,' in line:
        omega_values = re.findall(r'omega,\s+Initial\s+residual\s+=\s+(.*),\s+Final\s+residual\s+=\s+(.*),\s+No\s+Iterations\s+(.*)', line)
        if omega_values:
            omega_rate = omega_values[0]
            (omega_initial, omega_FinalRes, omega_Iters) = omega_rate
        for t in iteration_time:
            print ("%s\t%s\n" %(t, omega_initial))
```